# Identifying DBSCAN parameters (MinPts, eps)

Tags: cluster-analysis, knn, dbscan

I am new to python and machine learning. I am trying to cluster my dataset by using the DBSCAN algorithm. But I am stuck with getting correct values for MinPts and eps. I checked several solutions and didn't find a way to choose the values for those parameters. How can I choose those value, better if can explain it briefly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parameter estimation in DBSCAN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15050389/parameter-estimation-in-dbscan)

Comment: Completely I don't have an idea about how many clusters(domain knowledge) should be there as I used location data to cluster the area.

Comment: As stated in the above answer, there is no way to determine good values per se. You have to experiment with different values. Choose different eps and MinPts and see what happens. Do you know if the distances are more likely to be kilometers or nanometers? You can adjust your eps accordingly. Try to visualize your results. Are the points clustered to much? Try reducing minpoints and/or eps. If they are clustered to little try the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

In the [original publication](https://www.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/Publikationen/Papers/KDD-96.final.frame.pdf) (section 4.2) of DBSCAN the authors proposed a way to determine good values for *MinPoints* and *eps*.

They also ran tests that show that you can elimiate the *MinPoints* parameter for a 2-dimensional dataset by always using *MinPoints* = 4. Because there results for values greater than 5 are not significantly different than the ones with *MinPoints* = 4 but they are computationaly more expensive.